# default.properties error

Tags: android, properties

I have a project which I have copied from my old workspace to a new workspace. But I am getting this error  `Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.`

But the problem is my project has a default.properties file in it. But still I get this error. 
Can anyone suggest me with ideas about what is going wrong in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove R.java then generate again.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one) same problem with you.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I agree with [Edy Cu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/473962/edy-cu). But also considering changing the `Target API` (in properties) also might help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the project: project -> clean. It will generate R.java file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename your project.properties file to default.properties ... You got it done ;)