# How to resolve The default properties to set one in android

Tags: android

I have imported the project on my eclipse and th get the error 
2012-01-09 13:03:01 - Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
i have tried to copy the default project from other existing project and paste it on my new project which i have import but same error i get it , i am stuck cant move further how to resolve this error

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: 2012-01-09 13:03:01 -Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

Comment: if you ensure the default.properties existed in your project, you can try clean the project and rebuld, or close the project and re-open it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one

Answer (score 0):

If its a simple project, you could instead create a new Project using existing source