# Yet another "failed to load properties file"

Tags: android, eclipse

...plus **every** project has "Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one."

I just booted up my Eclipse 3.72 (Indigo) development environment (Windows XP) for Android on returning from AnDevConIII and every one of the 20 projects in my workspace said 
*Failed to load properties file for project* (xxxxxx).

There have been a million questions on this problem on StackOverflow and elsewhere but I have yet to see a definitive answer.

What, **exactly**, is the the properties file for a given project?    Where is it, what is it called, how is it created?

I've already deleted my debug keystore files, done a complete clean and build, and restarted Eclipse.   To the best of my knowledge I have made no changes of upgrades to my environment.

Help!   Thanks in advance!

Comment: What SDK & ADT version do you use at the moment?

Comment: list the properties file names in one of the projects

Answer (score 2):

> properties file for a given project? Where is it, what is it called,
>   how is it created?

Properties file is the main file for the project which *give information like Build Project Target and Library Dependencies*.

This file is *auto generated* when you specify any API level for you project.

There are two different names according the with ADT level for that file *"default.properties"* and *"project.properties"*

You can see this file direct under your project folder.

> Have To check

There is a view in Eclipse under `Window-Show View-Problems` in that, there will be a *sure indication of the problem while you try to build/run the project* that what is the actual error,and if you find any then paste that in your question here (also give a try to goole)

> Also Check

if the file with appropriate name with the current ADT level is exist in your project.

> Common Solutions But first check in problems recommanded

- to re-generate your `debug.keystore` file
- to remove project from wrokspace and import again
- right click project folder and `Android Tools-Fix project properties`

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a file named `project.properties` located at the root of your project in eclipse.

For example, you should see `AndroidManifest.xml`, and right below it `project.properties`.  Both of these plus some more files maybe.

here is what mine contains:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available   properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-8
```

Note the only line that is not commented out is `target=android-8`

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

just realized why this is probably happening-- did you recently upgrade your ADT? AFAIK this project.properties requirement is relatively new, maybe around v14.

Comment: All the projects in question have project.properties file closely resembling your above example.   They're all in the same folder as their manifest.   Yet the Eclipse error logs says, "Failed to load properties file for project 'Threads1'" (5 times each time I try to build it).
"

Comment: if you go: `file -> new -> new android project` and create a new empty project from scratch, do you still get this error?

Comment: No I do not have any problems if I create a new project from scratch.  But I have 20 other apps in that workspace, so I still need to understand where and what the "properties file is and how to repair it.

Comment: here's a similar thread with a lot of possibilites.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can delete your debug certificate under the directory is something like

> %USERPROFILE%/.androidon.

Then you may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was successful to follow the idea of MKJParekh

I deleted the debug.keystone in my %USERPROFILE% folder!