# Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one

Tags: android

Because of some problem I restored my XP. but now some of my projects don't work.
it giving me the following error:

`"Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one."`

I dont know what to do? Plz Help.Thanks in Advance!!!!
I also backed up my .android folder from system drive.

Comment: whr to find default.properties file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one).

Don't import it into Eclipse, use create new project from existing source in Eclipse

Comment: But I dont have default.properties file in project

Answer (score 35):

Going to the `Properties` → `Android` and setting a target won't work since setting the target won't create the project.properties file.

The fix is to:

- Manually create an empty project.properties file in the project root folder.
- Open the `Properties` → `Android`
- Set the desired Target
- Refresh the project

After this the error should be gone.

Comment: If you find you already have a project.properties file, just change the "target=android-xx" to the version you are using, but make sure in the used/correct android version is actually the one you enter here.

Answer (score 10):

Mouse over any error in your java import line then press <kbd>F2</kbd>, scroll down and choose `Fix project setup`. A project setup fixes dialogbox will appear, then press ok.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, and select properties-> chose android-> set Target.

Comment: No its not work for Me.thanks for ur quick response