# Error when importing an existing project to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

So I'm trying to import an existing project to eclipse and when I do I get the following error. The main folder of the project in the package explorer has a red exclamation mark (!) next to it and console says the same error 3 times:

```
[2013-07-10 14:23:39 - Myproject1] Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
[2013-07-10 14:23:39 - Myproject1] Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
[2013-07-10 14:23:39 - Myproject1] Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
```

I did my research on this error and found a bunch of stuff on this website already but nothing helps. People are mostly getting this error when they try to execute the imported project, not as soon as they import it. I also tried setting the "target set" in the project properties, as the error tells me to, but I can't find where to set the "target set" anywhere in the properties.

One more thing worth mentioning also, if I open the src folder and try to open any of the *.java, everything is blank, the "code" opens but it's blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Set android target version in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: RightClick on app --> properties-->Andrid--> select one android version.

Comment: Possible duplicate Question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one)

Comment: @yatul as I already mentioned, if I try to open any kind of code, it's blank. Same goes for xml sadly, the code is completely blank

Comment: Try to start eclipse with `-clean` option. Sometimes this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file 'project.properties' is missing. It must reside in the root-folder of your project.
( Where the AndroidManifest.xml is located )
You should create a new android-project and import the sources and resources 
OR create it manually.

Example content for project.properties:

# Project target.
target=android-17

Greetings
Christopher

Comment: This question has been answered before :p
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that when I try to open prject.properties it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

set android target version on your project manifest xml file or eclipse ->right click project click **properties**->select **android** tab->check latest android version on the list like below screen shot:

[image]

after click **ok** button will apply wait some seconds after your issue will be solved!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this isn't the problem, the latest version of android already is checked here

Comment: @Matthew try to restart eclipse or your project manifest xml added target version?

Answer (score 0):

you should try fixing project properties:

rightClick on Project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.

That resolved my issue!

Comment: welcome :). I had same issue and was resolved using that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably importing your project folder on your workspace. In my case, i got that same error, so i just move the project folder to "**C:**" and tryed to import again. And bingo!