# Importing Android Listview refresh by pull, project-properties error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, project-properties

I'm fairly new to Android, and using open source material for my needs during Android projects.
Currently, for my internship assignment, I'm developing an Android application and want to apply a pull to refresh to the ListView. If found this implementation by Erik, a fellow user on SO.

https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

After trying to import the project, however, I get various errors stating that the project-properties haven't been set. Currently, I'm importing the project by downloading the zip and importing it as an existing Android project.

The exact error is: [2013-12-10 09:17:00 - PullToRefresh SampleProject] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

I get a whole list of other errors, but I think this is the root cause, since it generates multiple errors within files on the import of root libraries like 'android' in general.

Would anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: I've tried that Rohan, didn't give me the results I hoped for. Trying to get the example project working to look further into the implementation

Comment: see my answer to your question regarding Chris Banes' ActionBar-PullToRefresh, I think I found the easiest way for non-senior developers to integrate pull-to-refresh functionality into our projects http://stackoverflow.com/a/23272758/3184778

Answer (score 0):

You should import the project as Android project from existing source code and define the current sdk to compile it. The file project.properties specifies the currrent sdk to compile the project and if the project is android library or not.

Check here for more details 
[Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one)[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857576/project-has-no-default-properties-file-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one)

Comment: Thank you for your response. After importing the project as existing Android code I noticed that both folders have a project.properties file that defines the sdk, yet it still gives the error. Also, when I scroll through the code, it gives error-messages on multiple occasions. Is this just outdated code or does it still have something to do with defining the SDK?

Comment: The repository has 2 different Android projects. First import the library project as Android Project. If you get errors, try to check "Fix project setup".Setup the library project as Android Library Project (Project Properties/Android/check isLibrary). After that, you can import the sample project as an Android project. If you have some compilation problem you have to: click "Fix project setup" and link the library project to the current one (Project Properties/Android/Add Library/select library project) and setup android-10 as target. Make a clean of the project to refresh all references.